# using two drop down list on same page dot net mvc razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-select

I have two drop down lists on same web page:

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("businessType", (SelectList) ViewBag.list, " -- Select Business Type -- ") and 
@Html.DropDownList("state", (SelectList) ViewBag.list, " -- Select State -- ")
```

and controller:

```
var query2 = db.Database.SqlQuery<statedropDownModel>("stateDropDownSP");
ViewBag.list = new SelectList(query2.AsEnumerable(), "Code", "StateName", "--select2--");

var query = db.Database.SqlQuery<businessDropDownModel>("businesDropDownSP");
ViewBag.list = new SelectList(query.AsEnumerable(), "ID", "BusinessTypeName", "--select--");
```

Now Problem is that, these two drop down lists are population dynamically with different data, but, it got conflict and  same data is being populated in both the list.
 Any solution to it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `ViewBag.businessTypeList` for the first one and `ViewBag.stateList` for the second, which would also make the code much more readable?

Answer (score 0):

You are re-using the `ViewBag.list` variable, so you are only getting the values from the second query.

I would suggest returning this data in the model for your view.

Comment: can you have any code example that how i can return this data in model for view ?

Comment: If you are using MVC and don't know how to use view models, I suggest you follow some tutorials on that.  I would start with : http://www.asp.net/mvc/pluralsight